# Why does System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AcceptAsync complete with ConnectionReset after a long time of inactivity?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous

It appears that when you call `Socket.AcceptAsync` with a valid `SocketAsyncEventArgs` and have the `SocketAsyncEventArgs.Completed` event rigged properly and no connection is accepted for a very long period of time that it just resets the connection. Though, my `Socket.ReceiveTimeout` and `Socket.SendTimeout` are both zero.

I'm unsure of how to set the timeout for accepting connections and even if it's a good idea at all. Does anyone have a workaround and perhaps some information as to why this is the default behavior?

I [filed a bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/708327/) on Microsoft Connect to see if they have any reasoning behind why the timeout period is unstable. Sometimes it times out in five minutes and other times more than two hours.

Comment: Have you checked what's going on on the wire with wireshark or something? ConnectionReset should be related to some connected socket, not a listening socket.

Comment: I had originally assumed the same which is why I am so darn confused on this. I am running a test with wireshark logging as we speak and will post the results when it happens.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov You nailed it. Found the root of the problem finally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After playing around with this for a bit I have found that a single SYN -> SYN-ACK -> RST sequence will raise the `SocketAsyncEventArgs.Completed` event and cause the `SocketAsyncEventArgs.SocketError` property to become `SocketError.ConnectionReset`. It appears this is expected behavior but it's definitely a gotcha and should be documented better.

Anyone port scanning your server and doing a half-open SYN type scan will generate similar traffic and cause the same problem. To prevent denial of service vulnerabilities in the software, one should be handling this special condition.

Comment: How do you think it should be handled? Just swallow the exception or close the connection?

Comment: @HarryMexican You should capture the exception, release the resources, and start accepting once again. If you need to block SYN scans, you need a firewall supporting stateful packet inspection and automatic traffic filtering, or some very aggressive firewall rules.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this could help:
[Socket problem: TcpClient.GetStream with ReceiveTimeout throws Exception and connected state become false](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ncl/thread/7a2d724a-22c6-4ff2-9a7a-c2312ea4dd42/)

If the socket times out, you could also send it keep alive packets every few seconds (minutes).

You could also keep an eye on the connection using Netstat -an | findstr /i "PORT#".  You can find information about that at:
[TCP Connection States and Netstat Output](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137984/en-us)

I hope that helps track down your problem.